# How to start a terminal from a recovery USB flash drive

Tags: terminal, macos

On Mavericks I want to start the **terminal** when using my Live-USB.

Comment: Menubar > Utilities > Terminal or Menubar > Dienstprogramme > Terminal

Comment: You might want to separate this question into two parts: 1) How to start a terminal from a recovery USB flash drive and post another question 2) How to repair "unknown file system" Leave part 1 here, and make a new question to address part 2. You're likely to get more actionable information that way. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bash shell is available in [Maverick's Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) from the menubar under Utilities:

[image]

If you suspect that the internal recovery disk is compromised and cannot boot into it with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, you could try booting into the "internet recovery mode" with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>**Option**</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. It might take a minute or two to load the Terminal option.